# How to use InputBox to move to another form

Tags: vb.net

Here's my code

```
Private Sub BookButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BookButton.Click
    Dim Response = InputBox("Enter Employee ID", "Employee Confirmation", "Employee ID", 500, 700)

    If Response = "EmployeeTest" Then
        Form2.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid Employee ID, Please Try Again", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Invalid input")
    End If
End Sub
```

when i run the project, after the I entered the correct input, its back to Form1, nothing happens, the input box closed itself. I want to show Form2 after user entered the correct input

Comment: Your code works exactly as it should for me. Either you're not actually entering the value you're testing for or your project or system is broken. I'm guessing that you haven't actually bothered debugging the code, so do that now. Place a breakpoint on the `If` statement and see what the actual value of `Response` is. You can then step and see where execution goes. If it goes to the `Form2.Show` call and no form is shown then something is broken. That's not a programming issue but a system issue.

Comment: Could Form2 be showing on a different monitor?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no, i've check it, already debug the code but can't seem to find it. I create a new project and redesign whole system, its works as its should